# Make shell script rerun command on certain user input

Tags: command-line, bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script that randomizes my hostname but prints the random hostname and prompts me if I want to use this hostname for example

```
NEXTHOST=$(sed `perl -e "print int rand(99999)"`"q;d" /usr/share/dict/words)
echo "Do you want to use this hostname? (y/n)
read variable_name
if [ "$variable_name" = n ] ; then
```

(this is the part where I want it to rerun the command for NEXTHOST), I left out the code for "y" because I already understand that part.

How do I make it rerun the command if I input n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function for this and then use recursion. As an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Defining hostgen function
hostgen() {
    NEXTHOST=$(sed `perl -e "print int rand(99999)"`"q;d" /usr/share/dict/words)
    echo $NEXTHOST
    read -p 'Do you want to use this hostname? (y/n)' variable_name
    if [ "$variable_name" = "n" ]; then
        echo "Okay. I will generate again"
        hostgen
    else
        echo "Your final hostname is : $NEXTHOST"
        exit
    fi
}

#Run hostgen for the first time
hostgen
```

Note that I have not set the hostname in this yet. You can do that.